# Same revision tag on style CSS on two computers, different look!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, blob-cache, cache

2 computers , both use IE8, 1 CSS file with same revision  = 2 different look !

Told in another way. I'm having a publishing site that feed users with the same site and the same style file with the same revison.  (I don't know if the contents are the same, because I dont want to hard refresh the file). Each style file got a revision tag, is a encrypted hash. Ex: prod.min.css?rev=324nhj22lkj1s32498sr32498

Users tend to only use **F5** and not **CTRL + F5**.

What I think:
computer 1 render the site correct, get's the right style file and render it
computer 2 render the site with a LOCAL style css

Why? I thought that the revision tag would solve this problem?

Tried to flush blob-cache!

*** NB *** Suddenly the page got rendered correct! I haven't done anything so something fishy going on

Comment: What do you mean by revision tag? myfile.css **?rev=1** ? Yes, changing that, should help. Did you try to change it after you saw that computer 2 still renders the old css? Did you try with F12 (Developer Toolbar), on the CSS tab, to see what CSS is actually loaded by the page?

Comment: ex on a file 

prod.min.css?rev=324nhj22lkj1s32498sr32498 . Each time we do somthing on the file it gets a new revision tag (hash). I don't have access to the developer toolbar on the produciton environment